# flutter: how to customize cuperinoAlertDialog style?

Tags: flutter, dialog

I'm working with flutter. I want to make a CupertinoAlertDialog(iOS style is required). My problem is UI designers require the background color of the alert dialog should be `#F0F0F0`. But I can only adjust its theme into dark or light(e.g. following picture). The code I completed is placed below.

```
showCupertinoDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context){
                  return Theme(
                    data: ThemeData.dark(),
                    child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
                      title: Text('Title'),
                      content: Text('Some message here'),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text('Cancle'),
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text('OK'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              );
```

[image]

Is that possible? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the background color for CupertinoAlertDialog is hardcoded. However, you can create a custom dialog that can change the background color of it as well as the functions of the buttons.

You need to create a type Dialog for the showDialog function instead of showCupertinoDialog:

```
Dialog customDialog = Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0), // your color
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)), // change 40 to your desired radius
    child: CustomAlertDialog(),
);
```

I also created a stateless widget called CustomAlertDialog, but if you don't want to, you can replace the CustomAlertDialog() with its content.

```
class CustomAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: 150,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Some message here"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Cancel"),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // replace with your own functions
               },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("OK"),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(); // replace with your own functions
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Lastly, replace your whole showCupertinoDialog with this showDialog function:

```
showDialog(
              barrierDismissible: true, // set false if you dont want the dialog to be dismissed when user taps anywhere [![enter image description here][1]][1]outside of the alert
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return customDialog;
              },
            );
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV13A.png

Comment: Yes，your answer is kind of helpful. Thank you very much.